О соединительной и разделительной функции дефиса и тире
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ
Тема дефиса, тире, черты и черточки уже обсуждалась: Почему дефис так называется и когда это слово стали использовать в школьной литературе?
Но вопрос о разделительной и соединительной функции этих знаков не был раскрыт в той мере, чтобы преодолеть противоречивость названия дефиса как знака разделительного. Кроме того, в лингвистике существует термин гифен, которого нет в толковом словаре общеупотребительной лексики, но который имеет отношение ко всем указанным знакам.
Как же связаны связаны эти понятия с точки зрения их функциональной значимости?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА СЕ

Из толкового словаря:

ТИРЕ [рэ], неизм.; ср. [франц. tiret]. 1. Знак препинания в виде длинной горизонтальной чёрточки. Т. между подлежащим и сказуемым. Поставить т. Выделить вводное предложение при помощи двойного т. 2. Знак такого вида в азбуке Морзе; звуковой сигнал, большей по сравнению с точкой продолжительности, соответствующий этому знаку. Передавать текст посредством точек и т.
ДЕФИС [де] и [дэ], -а; м. [от лат. divisio - разделение]. Орфографический значок в виде короткой чёрточки, употребляемый для соединения частей слова (например: какой-либо, что-нибудь) или двух слов (например: путь-дорога, северо-восточный, Москва-река, какой-нибудь); а также в качестве знака переноса части слогов слова с одной строки на другую и в качестве знака сокращения слова (например: б-ка - библиотека, с.-х. - сельскохозяйственный). Дефисный, -ая, -ое. Д-ое написание слова.
Итак, уже из словаря видно, что дефис как короткая черта имеет функции соединения и разделения, но при этом термин дефис применительно к орфографическому написанию слов используется как соединительный знак. Две другие функции относятся к особо обозначенным темам.

Интересно посмотреть, как это тема выглядит в английском языке и вообще в лингвистике.

Гифен у греков — это черта? Да, гифен у греков — это черта. В древнегреческом языке так назывался дефис, который обозначал соединительную скобу или черту.
А что такое гифен как понятие? Hyphen — (гифен | hyphen) Греческий термин, употребляемый для обозначения процесса, состоящего в группировке воедино (hyph hen) элементов, обычно разделенных; таким образом, получается нечто вроде сложного слова (лат. simulac).   Пятиязычный словарь лингвистических терминов.
Дефис и тире в английском языке
hyphen — дефис (-)
en dash — короткое тире (–)
em dash — длинное тире (—)

Также статья интересна  тем, что в ней подробно изложены правила употребления тире и дефиса.

Дефис и его аллонимические названия/ параллельные номинации

Аллоним в переводе с греческого «другое имя» (allos — другой и onyma — имя)
Материал взят из статьи Многоликий дефис
(1) Итак, в названии гифен отражена соединительная функция:
В начале XVI в. в своих грамматических трактатах обозначение гифен использовал Максим Грек, а в конце XVI в. дефис стал известен как соединительная (съединительная), сохраняя, таким образом, первичную функцию гифена, т.е. знака соединительного, которую тот выполнял в древнегреческом языке. Под этим названием дефис встречается в 1591 г. в львовском издании «Адельфотиса» и позднее в «Грамматике словенской» Лаврентия Зизания.
(2) Но в дальнейшем появляется тема разделения: В первой половине XVII в. у Мелетия Смотрицкого дефис получил наименование разъятная, выступив в функции знака переноса. Эта функция до сих пор считается одной из основных функций дефиса, хотя в некоторых словарях современной лингвистической терминологии терминам дефис и знак переноса посвящены отдельные статьи.
С течением времени функция переноса подверглась конкретизации и в середине XVIII в. была дополнена сопутствующей ей функцией слогоделения (М.В. Ломоносов), а в начале XX в. - функцией членения слова на морфемы (Л.В. Щерба).
Итак, соединительную функцию имел термин гифен, отнесенный к графическому знаку в виде черты. Но потом этот же графический знак стал использоваться для обозначения разделительной функции при переносе слов или при членении слова на морфемы.  При этом сам  знак в виде черты не изменился, но стал совмещать в себе функции разделения и соединения.

Дальнейшее развитие темы

В настоящее время используются два графических знака — дефис и тире, которые различаются по длине. До этого они назывались чертой (тире) и черточкой (дефис). Другими словами, конкретная функция знака отсутствовала в названии, вот и не было противоречия "разделительного" дефиса.
Но затем, вероятно,  появилась необходимость в стандартизации языковых норм  при обозначении терминов. Поэтому короткая черта/черточка названа общим словом дефис, но при этом в орфографии слов она имеет функцию соединения, а при переносе слов или других членениях эта функция будет разделительной.
Ну и в общем случае дефис — это промежуточный знак между слитным и раздельным написанием слов, то есть он как бы уходит от слитного написания (делит слова), но в то же время обозначает соединение, препятствуя полному разделению слов. Вот такая философия)
